# SQL issue with Case statement and joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

Here is an example of two tables (please see the SQLFiddle) and I trying to create a select statement where one table is lookup (Facility) and the other is data table (WOENTITY), I want to select get the facititynames from lookup and whenever it finds multiple entries of facilityID just write text as 'Multiple locations' or if it finds null or zero then write 'unknown' else just write the facilityname, I was trying to do a case to replace multiple counts with single entry. Any help is appreciated.

Link to SQL Fiddle : [Click Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0e30/4)

Here is the screenshot of how tables look like, Table WOEntity and Table Facility
[Image showing the table schema and expected end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDk2N.png)

I first thought of getting counts of multiple location Id from WOEntity Table and then create a select Case statement but no avail, here is the draft code.

```
select e.WOID, count(e.ENTITYUID) as CNT, 
    (case   
            when e.ENTITYUID <> '0' and count(e.ENTITYUID) <=1 then
                (Select FACILITYNAME from FACILITY l where e.ENTITYUID = 
                  l.FACILITYID)
            when count(e.ENTITYUID) > 2 then 'MULTIPLE FACILITIES'
            else 'UNKNOWN LOCATIONS'
    end) as facilityName
 From WOENTITY e
group by e.WOID order by WOID;
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, the expected result is where I want to group by only WOID but not the Entity. I want to see two columns, the distinct WOID (each entry of WOID) and the facility name (from lookup)

Comment: OP, when supplying additional information for your question, please do so by editing your original question.  Thank you, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, Thanks for the advice, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally do this with a `JOIN` rather than correlated subqueries, then use `COUNT` in the case expression:

```
SELECT  e.WOID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(f.FACILITYID) = 0 THEN 'UNKNOWN LOCATIONS'
            WHEN COUNT(f.FACILITYID) > 1 THEN 'MULTIPLE FACILITIES'
            ELSE MAX(f.FACILITYNAME)
        END AS facilityName
FROM    WOENTITY AS e
        LEFT JOIN FACILITY AS f
            ON f.FACILITYID = e.ENTITYUID
GROUP BY e.WOID
ORDER BY e.WOID;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0e30/20)**

Since you deal with the scenarios of more than one, or zero records matched by the JOIN, by the time you get to the `ELSE` you only have one record, so although you are using the `MAX` aggregate function, you only have one input row, so this is not really doing anything, other than allowing you to select the facility name without grouping by it.

**EDIT**

I have just noticed that Canada should show as multiple locations, even though only one of them exists in the facilities table, in which case you need to change the case expresison slightly, changing `COUNT(f.FACILITYID)` to `COUNT(*)` for the second predicate:

```
SELECT  e.WOID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(f.FACILITYID) = 0 THEN 'UNKNOWN LOCATIONS'
            WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'MULTIPLE FACILITIES'
            ELSE MAX(f.FACILITYNAME)
        END AS facilityName
FROM    WOENTITY AS e
        LEFT JOIN FACILITY AS f
            ON f.FACILITYID = e.ENTITYUID
GROUP BY e.WOID
ORDER BY e.WOID;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0e30/39)**

Comment: thanks for your response, The edit looks good, I am testing the results in actual data (thousands of records), so far so good. I also found the solution from@ Horaciux works fine too. Is it safe to assume both yours and Horaciux does the same thing? will post the result in few more tests

Answer (score 0):

as the statement say to you you missed one gorup by params ... somthing like:

```
select e.WOID, count(e.ENTITYUID) as CNT, 
    (case   
            when e.ENTITYUID <> '0' and count(e.ENTITYUID) <=1 then
                (Select FACILITYNAME from FACILITY l where e.ENTITYUID = 
                  l.FACILITYID) 
            when count(e.ENTITYUID) > 2 then 'MULTIPLE FACILITIES'
            else 'UNKNOWN LOCATIONS'
    end) as facilityName
 From WOENTITY e
group by e.WOID,e.ENTITYUID order by WOID;
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I dont want to group by EntityUid because this makes the distinct WOID go away, I want to see single entry for each WOID and its facility name. from your code above, i see WOID is repeated multiple times

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of @GarethD answer that contemplates the case similar to 'Canada'

```
  SELECT  e.WOID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(f.FACILITYID) = 0 THEN 'UNKNOWN LOCATIONS'
            WHEN COUNT(f.FACILITYID) >0 and  COUNT(coalesce(f.FACILITYID,'x'))>COUNT(f.FACILITYID)  then 'MULTIPLE OFFICES'
            WHEN COUNT(f.FACILITYID) > 1 then 'MULTIPLE OFFICES'
            ELSE MAX(f.FACILITYNAME)
        END AS facilityName
FROM    WOENTITY AS e
        LEFT JOIN FACILITY AS f
            ON f.FACILITYID = e.ENTITYUID
GROUP BY e.WOID
ORDER BY e.WOID;
```

Comment: @Horacius, thanks for your response, I dont want to group by EntityUid because this makes the distinct WOID go away, I want to see single entry for each WOID and its facility name. from your code above, i see WOID is repeated multiple times

Comment: @Abdul See my edit, it brings you expected results now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Select FACILITYID,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM  WOEnTITY 
               WHERE WOEnTITY.ENTITYUID = FACILITYID)  > 0 
         THEN 'MULTIPLE LOCATIONS' 
         ELSE '' 
    END
FROM FACILITY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
Select Row_Number() over(order by Id) as Id, Woid, Case when FACILITYID is null then 'UNKNOWN LOCATIONS'
               when RowCnt > 1 then 'MULTIPLE OFFICES' else FACILITYNAME end as FacilityName,
               RowCnt as CountFacilities 
               from (
    Select *, RowCnt = count(EntityUid) over(partition by woid),
    RowN = Row_Number() over(Partition by woid order by Id)
    from WOENTITY we
    left join Facility f
    on we.ENTITYUID = f.FACILITYID
) a
Where a.RowN = 1
```

Output as below:

```
+----+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Id |  Woid   |   FacilityName    | CountFacilities |
+----+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Canada  | MULTIPLE OFFICES  |               2 |
|  2 | Germany | GREEN             |               1 |
|  3 | India   | GREEN             |               1 |
|  4 | UK      | RED               |               1 |
|  5 | US      | MULTIPLE OFFICES  |               3 |
|  6 | JAPAN   | UNKNOWN LOCATIONS |               1 |
+----+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
```